# how remove commits from PR

Tags: git, github

I've created a pull request but initially as I understand I created this new branch from the branch which is old. I created two branched.

After I need to merge these branches into master but when creating a PR, I can see that both these two branches have this history:

1 branch

- another guy commit
- another guy commit
- another guy commit
- my commit

2 branch

- another guy commit
- another guy commit
- another guy commit
- another guy commit
- another guy commit
- my commit

GREEN - my commits

BLACK - commits I want to delete from this branch.

The problem is that both of these PRs have my changes and BOTH have the same commits from another developer. How can I delete these commits and only merge to master my commits?

For future I will only create branch from the master/main.

[image]

Comment: Most likely rebasing will fix the issue. But is it an actual problem if those commits are already there? They won’t be applied twice

Comment: Definetly rebase will help in this scenrio but I can help you with remote access(if you'll want)

Comment: I agree with the above two comments: you need a rebase. Run an interactive rebase and choose the commits you want to keep. Then you'll need to force push the changed PR branch so that your PR just has the history you want to include and not those other changes. If this is going to merged into `main`, you probably want `git rebase -i main`, delete the commits you don't want from the list shown, and you should be set.